# .length() doesn't fill a new variable jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function where I want to read the length of the path of a image source and use it in an if else clause but the variable which it is supposed to contain the numeric value seems empty. Neither the if clause nor the else one is being used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function imgresize(img){
var strl=img.src.length;
  if(strl<10)
  {
    //do someting
  }
  else
    //do something
}
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <img onclick="imgresize(this)" src="image1.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why this strl variable is not being filled?

Comment: If neither the if block nor the else block is being executed, the problem is not with the variable but that the function isn't being called at all.

Comment: There is probably a JavaScript error in your code. Have a look at the console. What is `img`?

Comment: Can you build a fiddle demonstrating the problem (for example at http://jsbin.com) and give more code ?

Comment: did you try printing strl and see what you get?

Comment: How are you verifying neither the if not the else is being executed?

Comment: Hello str, 
img is an image that is passed from a <img> tag.

<img onclick="imgresize(this)" src="image1.png">

Comment: By the way, now that the answers are gone, it's still relevant to note that comparing with `"10"` instead of `10` involves an unnecessary cast and is bad.

Comment: It's most likely that there's a syntax error somewhere that halts script execution. Do you know where the JavaScript error console is and are there errors in it?

Comment: Nope, still looks ok. It seems like you're using JS Bin -- could you give a link to your code there so we could try it out? What about that error console?

Answer (score 1):

## Try this out:

**http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/Fg3CB/**

JS Code:-

```
function imgresize(img) {
    var strl = img.src.length;
    if (strl < 10) {
        alert("Length smaller than 10");
    } else{
        alert("Length greater than 10");
    }
}
```

HTML Code:-

```
<img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQTkCsSOSfmGx9uq2EvOeq65-oZBlIzvqSKnqgNgrDEsPn1b7xr" alt="etstst" onclick="imgresize(this);">
```

Comment: it worked the comparation without quotes for the numeric value 10. In addition, I realized the complete path is used, so the length is more than 10 characters (it is /home/fofo/image1.png), so it will never be executed what it is inside the if clause.

Comment: Actually the comparation only works with img.src and not with img.attr('src').
ThanX guys...it is awesome how you give an answer so quickly :)

Comment: @user1013213 It would be even more awesome if you could (in the future) answer to people when they ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

live fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PucCp/)

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/256/Positive.png" alt="etstst" onclick="imgresize(this);">
<img src="zzzz" alt="etstst" onclick="imgresize(this);">
```

**jQuery**

```
function imgresize(img) {
    var stringlen =  $(img).attr('src').length;
    alert("length is : " + stringlen);
    if (stringlen < 10) {
        alert("Length smaller than 10");
    } else{
        alert("Length greater than 10");
    }
}
```